# RuntimeError: no running event loop

Tags: python-3.x, websocket

I am new in python. I have created the code but it's not working. Everytime i am getting error. My requirement is. I want to run the code for ever, client will send the user id to the websocket server and code will add the client's data into a list and every 3 sesond client will get the notification.

loop = events.get_running_loop()
RuntimeError: no running event loop
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'sendNotification' was never awaited

```
`import asyncio
import base64
from random import random
import websockets
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, SmallInteger, TIMESTAMP
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import LONGTEXT
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
import json
import threading
import socket
import phpserialize
import ssl



Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column('user_id', Integer)
    email = Column('email',String(255))
    password = Column('password', String(255))
    active = Column('active', String(255))
    user_type = Column('user_type', String(4))
    remember_token = Column('remember_token', String(100))
    first_login = Column('first_login', SmallInteger)
    created_at = Column('created_at', TIMESTAMP)
    updated_at = Column('updated_at', TIMESTAMP)


    def __init__(self, id, user_id, email, password, active, user_type, remember_token, first_login, created_at, updated_at):
        self.id = id
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.active = active
        self.user_type = user_type
        self.remember_token = remember_token
        self.first_login = first_login
        self.created_at = created_at
        self.updated_at = updated_at


    def to_json(self):
        return dict(id=self.id, user_id=self.user_id,email=self.email, password=self.password,active=self.active, user_type=self.user_type,remember_token=self.remember_token, first_login=self.first_login,created_at=self.created_at, updated_at=self.updated_at)


class RoleNotification(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'role_notifications'
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    role_id = Column('role_id', Integer)
    notifications = Column('notifications', LONGTEXT)
    view_conf = Column('view_conf', LONGTEXT)
    created_at = Column('created_at', TIMESTAMP)
    updated_at = Column('updated_at', TIMESTAMP)


    def __init__(self, id, role_id, notifications, view_conf, created_at, updated_at):
        self.id = id
        self.role_id = role_id
        self.notifications = notifications
        self.view_conf = view_conf
        self.created_at = created_at
        self.updated_at = updated_at


    def to_json(self):
        return dict(id=self.id, role_id=self.role_id, notifications=self.notifications, view_conf=self.view_conf, created_at=self.created_at, updated_at=self.updated_at)


class RoleUser(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'role_user'
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column('user_id', Integer)
    role_id = Column('role_id', Integer)


    def __init__(self, id, user_id, role_id):
        self.id = id
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.role_id = role_id


    def to_json(self):
        return dict(id=self.id, user_id=self.user_id, role_id=self.role_id)




connection_string = "mysql+mysqlconnector://dev_msql:123456@localhost:3306/myportal"
engine = create_engine(connection_string, echo=True)





Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()


# Websocket program starts here

host = '0.0.0.0'
port = 23743
clients = []


async def addClient(websocket, path):
    try:
        async for message in websocket:
            if message:
                clients.append({'id': message, 'sock':websocket})



    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed as e:
        if len(clients) > 0:
            for client in clients:
                if client.get('sock') == websocket:
                    clients.remove(client)
                    break
    finally:
        pass



async def sendNotification():
    while True:
        for conn in clients:
            role_id = session.query(RoleUser).filter(RoleUser.user_id == conn.get('id')).first().role_id
            roleNotification = session.query(RoleNotification).filter(RoleNotification.role_id == role_id).first()
            totalNotification = {}
            if roleNotification:
                notification = phpserialize.loads(data=bytes(roleNotification.notifications, 'utf-8'),
                clientId = 'u' + str(conn.get('id'))
                if notification:

                    newTask = notification.get('new_task', None)
                    if newTask:
                        _newTask = newTask.get(clientId, None)
                        if _newTask:
                            newTask = _newTask
                        else:
                            newTask = None

                    totalNotification['success'] = 1
                    totalNotification['newTask'] = [newTask]

            await conn.get('sock').send(json.dumps(totalNotification))
            await asyncio.sleep(random() * 3)




# Start the server
start_server = websockets.serve(addClient, host, port)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.create_task(sendNotification())
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```